# Is it possible to set a TFS task that decompiles code?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm currently trying to set up a TFS Task for CI. I see options to compile code but I'm trying to decompile code to check for differences between live code and what is in source control before deploying the code.

I'm sorry if it's not completely clear what I'm trying to do and I'll clarify as necessary.

Edit: I am aware that I can run a command line to decompile the code, but I am wanting to see if there is a "built in" TFS task to do it...

To clarify, I am using the TFS Web Portal

Comment: Be aware that decompiled code does not necessarily look like the original code. Also, isn't your live code already in TFS? Why are you trying to do the comparison _after_ you've compiled the code? This sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I am trying to compare the code in a development server to what is in source control before deploying to staging. Edit: development and staging environments, forgive me if the terminology I'm using is incorrect...

Comment: But **why** do you want to compare the code? What would that achieve?

Comment: Checking to see if someone has directly edited what's in development without updating source control

Comment: to try and insure what's on development and what's on staging is the same

Comment: This is a discipline/culture problem. A developer who worked for me that started circumventing source control as a regular practice would be fired.

Comment: It is unfortunate but is not an extremely common occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is built-in build task to decompile code. Since you can run a command line to decompile the code, you could add a [Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/command-line) task in your build definition to run the commands. Or you could [develop your own build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview) to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for providing links to this, I was unaware you can develop your own tasks. Also, how do I mark your answer as the answer? I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow...

Comment: Nvm, I figured out how to make it as an answer :) thanks again for the help.